# How to check if string is a pangram?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, pangram

I want to create a function which takes a string as input and check whether the string is pangram or not (pangram is a piece of text which contains every letter of the alphabet).

I wrote the following code, which works, but I am looking for an alternative way to do it, hopefully a shorted way.

```
import string

def is_pangram (gram):
    gram = gram.lower()
    gram_list_old = sorted([c for c in gram if c != ' '])
    gram_list = []
    for c in gram_list_old:
        if c not in gram_list:
            gram_list.append(c)
    if gram_list == list(string.ascii_lowercase): return True
    else: return False
```

I feel like this question might be against the rules of this website but hopefully it isn't. I am just curious and would like to see alternative ways to do this.

Comment: Can there be punctuation and whitespace in 'piece of text'?

Comment: I didn't think of that. In the code above, I delete all whitespace, so I would do the same to punctuation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
is_pangram = lambda s: not set('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') - set(s.lower())

>>> is_pangram('abc')
False
>>> is_pangram('the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog')
True
>>> is_pangram('Does the quick brown fox jump over the lazy dog?')
True
>>> is_pangram('Do big jackdaws love my sphinx of quartz?')
True
```

> Test string `s` is a pangram if we start with the alphabet, remove every letter found in the test string, and all the alphabet letters get removed.

**Explanation**

The use of 'lambda' is a way of creating a function, so it's a one line equivalent to writing a `def` like:

```
 def is_pangram(s):
     return not set('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') - set(s.lower())
```

`set()` creates a data structure which can't have any duplicates in it, and here:

- The first set is the (English) alphabet letters, in lowercase
- The second set is the characters from the test string, also in lowercase. And all the duplicates are gone as well.

Subtracting things like `set(..) - set(..)` returns the contents of the first set, minus the contents of the second set. `set('abcde') - set('ace') == set('bd')`.

In this pangram test:

- we take the characters in the test string away from the alphabet
- If there's nothing left, then the test string contained all the letters of the alphabet and must be a pangram.
- If there's something leftover, then the test string did not contain all the alphabet letters, so it must not be a pangram.
- any spaces, punctuation characters from the test string set were never in the alphabet set, so they don't matter.

`set(..) - set(..)` will return an empty set, or a set with content. If we force sets into the simplest True/False values in Python, then containers with content are 'True' and empty containers are 'False'.

So we're using `not` to check "is there anything leftover?" by forcing the result into a True/False value, depending on whether there's any leftovers or not.

`not` also changes True -> False, and False -> True. Which is useful here, because (alphabet used up) -> an empty set which is `False`, but we want `is_pangram` to return `True` in that case. And vice-versa, (alphabet has some leftovers) -> a set of letters which is `True`, but we want `is_pangram` to return `False` for that.

Then return that True/False result.

```
is_pangram = lambda s: not set('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') - set(s.lower())
#      Test string `s`
#is a pangram if
#                           the alphabet letters 
#                                                             minus 
#                                                               the test string letters
#                   has NO leftovers
```

Comment: Wow, this method is great! I still don't understand it at the moment but will read the docs and hopefully understand it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Really appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 4):

You can use something as simple as:

```
import string
is_pangram = lambda s: all(c in s.lower() for c in string.ascii_lowercase)
```

Comment: Nice! I had a feeling it could be done much shorter.

Comment: By the way, what does `all` do here?

Comment: `all()` returns `True` if all elements in the list are `True`. See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) for definition.

Comment: brackets can be removed in the `all()`

Comment: @monkut Why? Because of lambda expression?

Comment: `all()` without brackets will create/use a generator expression, providing the `[]` will create a list evaluated by all.  There are discussions of which is faster in certain cases, but imho if you data is small the bracketless solution is cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

Sets are excellent for membership testing:

```
>>> import string
>>> candidate = 'ammdjri * itouwpo ql ? k @ finvmcxzkasjdhgfytuiopqowit'
>>> ascii_lower = set(string.ascii_lowercase)
```

Strip the whitespace and punctuation from the candidate then test:

```
>>> candidate_lower = ascii_lower.intersection(candidate.lower())
>>> ascii_lower == candidate_lower
False
```

Find out what is missing:

```
>>> ascii_lower.symmetric_difference(candidate_lower)
set(['b', 'e'])
```

Try it again but add the missing letters:

```
>>> candidate = candidate + 'be'
>>> candidate_lower = ascii_lower.intersection(candidate.lower())
>>> ascii_lower == candidate_lower
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 def pangram(word):
      return all(chr(c+97) in word for c in range(25))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about simply check whether each one of the lowercased alphabet is in the sentence:

```
text = input()
s = set(text.lower())

if sum(1 for c in s if 96 < ord(c) < 123) == 26:
    print ('pangram')
else:
    print ('not pangram')
```

or in a function:

```
def ispangram(text):
    return sum(1 for c in set(text.lower()) if 96 < ord(c) < 123) == 26
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another definition:

```
def is_pangram(s):
    return len(set(s.lower().replace(" ", ""))) == 26
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the easiest and without using module programe.

```
def checking(str_word):
b=[]
for i in str_word:
    if i not in b:
        b.append(i)
b.sort()
#print(b)
#print(len(set(b)))
if(len(set(b))>=26):
    print(b)
    print(len(b))
    print(" String is  pangram .")

else:
        print(" String isn't pangram .")
    #b.sort()
#print(b)


str_word=input(" Enter the String :")
checking(str_word)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this thread is a little old, but I thought I'd throw in my solution anyway.

```
import string

def panagram(phrase):
    new_phrase=sorted(phrase.lower())
    phrase_letters = ""
    for index in new_phrase:
        for letter in string.ascii_lowercase:
            if index == letter and index not in phrase_letters:
                phrase_letters+=letter
    print len(phrase_letters) == 26
```

or for the last line:

```
    print phrase_letters == string.ascii_lowercase
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def panagram(phrase):
alphabet="abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
pharseletter=""
for char in phrase:
    if char in aphabet:
        phraseletter= phraseletter + char
for char in aplhabet:
    if char not in phrase:
        return false
```

Comment: Care: You write `pharseletter=""`. then `phraseletter= phraseletter +...` next bug!

Answer (score 0):

```
import string
def ispangram(str, alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase):
    alphabet = set(alphabet)    
    return alphabet <= set(str.lower())
```

## or more simpler way

```
def ispangram(str):
    return len(set(str.lower().replace(" ", ""))) == 26
```

Comment: This is the most perfect answer !

Answer (score 0):

```
import string

def is_pangram(phrase, alpha=string.ascii_lowercase):
     num = len(alpha)
     count=0

for i in alpha:
    if i in phrase:
        count += 1
return count == num
```

Comment: Please provide explanation to your code and justify why it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
def panagram(str1):
    str1=str1.replace(' ','').lower()
    s=set(str1)
    l=list(s)
    if len(l)==26:
        return True
    return False




str1='The quick brown fox jumps over the dog'
q=panagram(str1)
print(q)
```

> > True

Answer (score 0):

```
import string
def ispangram(str1,alphabet=string.ascii.lowercase):  
for myalphabet in alphabet:
    if myalphabet not in str1:
        print(it's not pangram)
        break
    else:
        print(it's pangram)
```

Execute the command:

```
ispangram("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")
```

Output: "it's pangram." 
Hint: `string.ascii_lowercase` returns output

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s;
        char f;
         Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        s = in.nextLine();

        char[] charArray = s.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        final Set set = new HashSet();

        for (char a : charArray) {
            if ((int) a >= 97 && (int) a <= 122) {
                f = a;
                set.add(f);
            }

        }
        if (set.size() == 26){
            System.out.println("pangram");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("not pangram");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import string
import re
list_lower= list(string.lowercase);
list_upper=list(string.uppercase);
list_total=list_lower + list_upper ;
def is_panagram(temp):
    for each in temp:
        if each not in list_total :
            return 'true'
sample=raw_input("entre the string\n");
string2=re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', sample)
ram=is_panagram(string2);
if ram =='true':
    print "sentence is not a panagram"
else:`enter code here`
    print"sentece is a panagram"
```