# Whats wrong with my python pangram function

Tags: python, function, pangram

Its a function that checks whether a string is a [Pangram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangram) or not
so if `str1 == 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'` the function will return True since the string contains every letter in the alphabet.

```
import string

def ispangram(str1, alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase):
    for char in set(alphabet): 
        if char in str1:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  To help us answer your question, please include more details, including what the expected output of your code is and what you're getting.

Comment: Isn't it just going to end the function (returning either `True/False`) after the first time it hits a `return` line?

Comment: Flip the `if` and `return True` outside the loop, otherwise you're just returning True for the first character that is present in the input string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if string is a pangram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771381/how-to-check-if-string-is-a-pangram)

Answer (score 3):

As soon as a first letter is found in the `str1`, the function returns `True`.

What you need to do instead is:

```
def ispangram(str1, alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase):
    for char in set(alphabet): 
        if char not in str1:
            return False
    return True
```

This way the function returns `False` only if `char` is not in `str1` and only after all the characters are found to be present in the `str1` it returns `True`.

You might want to use `str1.lower()`, because you are checking for lowercase letters only.

Comment: Oh, that makes much more sense. Thank you!

Comment: What does `set` do for you in `for char in set(alphabet):`?  Shouldn't it work just as well without converting `alphabet` to a `set`?

Comment: `for char in alphabet:` will work just as well, but may not be as quick when a character is present multiple times in `alphabet`. Also, I'm editing the original code and merely pointing out the part causing the problem, without doing additional edits that may obfuscate the actual fix.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly what your function is supposed to do, I suspect the issue is that you return either `True` or `False` in the first iteration of the loop, so only the first letter is ever analyzed. Try this:

```
import string

def ispangram(str1, alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase):
    for char in set(alphabet): 
        if char not in str1:
            return False

    return True
```

Comment: What does `set `do for you in `for char in set(alphabet):`? Shouldn't it work just as well without converting `alphabet` to a `set`?

Comment: It would still work, the only thing `set()` accomplishes is that, in the case where there are duplicates in the alphabet, these duplicates need only be evaluated once, which could in some cases be more computationally expensive then generating the set

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach from yours:

```
import string

def ispangram(str1, alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase):
    return len(set(l.lower() for l in str1 if l.lower() in alphabet)) == len(alphabet)

print(ispangram("I am very tired, but I will keep programming to pass the quiz!"))
```

Output:

```
False
```

Comment: You don't need the explicit returns of `True` and `False`, simply `return len(set(...)) == len(alphabet)`.  The function doesn't need to know the answer, only the caller.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to `set(alphapet)`, you can iterate `alphabet` directly.

If you in the condition that function will return `False` then the function will exit without executing the following lines so after finishing the for-loop without returning false then we have *pangram* case so the function will directly return `True`.

```
import string

def ispangram(str1, alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase):
    for char in alphabet: 
        if char not in str1:
            return False         
    return True

str1 = 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
print(ispangram('Hello')) #False
print(ispangram(str1)) #True
```

However, we can shorten our function using [`all()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19389490/10851804) to be

```
def ispangram(str1, alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase):
    return all([char in  str1 for char in alphabet])
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted elsewhere, you have your logic inverted and incorrectly indented.  But your design is nice in that it naturally ignores characters that aren't letters.  I would add some defense against mixed case and simplify it slightly:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet

def ispangram(string):
    string = string.lower()

    for character in alphabet:
        if character not in string:
            return False

    return True


print(ispangram('Watch "Jeopardy!", Alex Trebek\'s fun TV quiz game.'))
```

Comment: @AnnZen, first, reducing to a 'one liner' isn't the goal of all Python.  Second, you blew it.  By including the `[...]` brackets you made it a `list` comprehension that needs to complete before calling `all()` -- thus shortcutting on the first miss goes out the window so it is *less* efficient than my original.  If you had left out the `[...]` brackets, then it would be a *generator expression* and would shortcut correctly, returning `False` on the first miss.

Comment: Your function can be shortened to a liner: def ispangram(string):     return all(character in string.lower() for character in alphabet)

Comment: I agree, never said it was :) Still, I think using `all()` would be more pythonic. Thanks for the pointers about the generator.

Comment: @AnnZen, your one liner calls `string.lower()` on *every* iteration when it only needs to be lower cased once.

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns True if any alphabet characters are found in your string. Is that what you wanted? It runs through the cars in `set(alphabet)`, and if any of them are in your string `if char in str1`, it returns True. That doesn't seem very useful for your goal. You probably want more complicated logic, that checks the order of characters, whether the string is identical when reversed if you are looking at palindromes, etc. Hope this helps guide you!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the input `"abc"`.  When your function iterates through the letters in the alphabet, it starts with `"a"`, sees that it's in the input string, and then returns `True`. You need to check to make sure that *all* the letters from the alphabet are in the input string

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns directly after checking the first character of `alphabet`, regardless of whether the character in in `str1`. In fact, you function simply checks if some character of the alphabet is in you string.

What you intended to do was:

```
import string

def ispangram(str1, alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase):
    for char in set(alphabet): 
        if char not in str1:
            return False
    else:
        return True
```

However, a much simpler solution would simply be:

```
def ispangram(str1, alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase)
    return set(str1) >= set(alphabet)
```

Comment: your seem to have had the same thoughts as me, but i dropped the set option as normally pangrams are sentences contain more than just ascii chars, like spaces or punctuation which makes the set not match

Comment: Need to do something like `return set(string.ascii_lowercase) == set([char for char in str1 if char in string.ascii_lowercase])`

Comment: Or just use `>=`

Comment: even better idea

Comment: Can you explain the set(str1) >= set(alphabet): part?

Comment: @Harry - superset relation. `str1` contains all characters in `alphabet`, but possibly other characters, like punctuation, spaces numbers or special symbols.